# Is there any way to convert GeneXus QueryViewer to PDF?

Tags: pdf, graph, report, genexus

I need to show a graph generated by UserControl QueryViewer (from GeneXus) into a PDF.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but only if the output is "Table" or "PivotTable".
You can find the property named "Export to PDF" in the upper right corner of the screen.

This is not available for Card, Chart or Map outputs.